# How to run .cc extension file in linux?

Tags: linux

I have main.cc file and i would like to run this file in linux. May i know what would be the correct way of executing this file ? Is it

```html
gcc -o x main.cc
```

? Any help or feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it would be `gcc main.cc -o main.ou` where `main.cc` is your main-file and `main.ou` your output file.

You can also read more about executing c/c++ files here:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/compiling-c-program-and-creating-executable-file/

Answer (score 0):

The command you gave will compile the file. The resulting executable is put in `x`. To run it, you do:

```
./x
```